# Want to redirect after login

Tags: php, yii

I wish to redirect my visitors to a specific page on my site 'data' after login.

how do I do this?

below is my code for the the login page.

```
<?php
    $this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Login';
?>
```

code removed as it is just a user, pass  fields.  i removed as it is not allowing me to submit without explaing the code.

```
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in ur controller after validating ..

```
public void redirect(mixed $url, boolean $terminate=true, integer $statusCode=302)
```

Refer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
header("Location: xxx"); 
die("");
```

Comment: No reason to do this when Yii has easier methods for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try in controller

```
$this->redirect($this->createUrl('your/url'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
if(isset($_POST['loginForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['loginForm'];
            // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
            if($model->validate() && $model->login())

                $this->redirect(array('admin/update'));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like:

```
Yii::app()->request->redirect( $yoururl );
```